# Set Email Recipients in PHP mail from checkbox array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, checkbox, phpmailer

I am creating a form in PHP where the user can email the information to the desired recipients by checking the box next to their name.

I first query the database and then create the checkboxes dynamically in a while loop. The checkboxes look like this.

```
<input name='email[]'  id='$email' value='$email' type='checkbox'>
```

On submit I Post the array

```
$students = $_POST['email'];
```

Then I set my subject, message and headers and use a foreach loop to set the recipients and send the message.

```
$subject = $planTitle; // Give the email a subject
$message = nl2br($_POST['planCont']); 
$headers = 'From:' . $user . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

foreach ($students as $to) {
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

I also tried putting the subject, message, and headers in the foreach loop but that didn't work either.

Shouldn't this work?

In order to test and see what might be happening I have tried just sending to one recipient and actually typing in the email address like student@example.com  and as a variable  like $user . These work so I know I am close.

My only two thoughts are that when I am logged in to test and send the message the $user email address is a gmail account.  I know there can be issues with that and I do not know if those issues might be kicking in when I try to send to the array.

The other guess I have is that somehow the network I am connected is freaking out but I am only testing by trying to send to an array of 3 email addresses so I wouldn't think that would be an issue.

Let me know any thoughts or if you need to see more code.

**EDIT**

Here some more of my code as requested.  I originally just ended my PHP after the while loop and then had the Title and Content in plain HTML. But I thought that might be causing the issue as well.

```
echo "<form method='post' action='' id='myPlan' data-ajax='false'>";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT first,last,email,grade,status FROM students WHERE ministryID='$ministryID2'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $first = $row['first'];
            $last = $row['last'];
            $email = $row['email'];
            $grade = $row['grade'];
            $status = $row['status'];

    echo "<tr class='myRow'><td style='padding-right:15px;'><input name='email[]'  id='email' value='$email' type='checkbox'></td><td>$last</td><td>$first</td><td>$grade</td><td>$status</td></tr>";
}

        echo "</table>";
        echo "<label><h2>Title</h2></label>
        <input type='text' name='planTitle' id='planTitle' value='' required>



        <label><h2>Content</h2></label>
        <textarea name='planCont' id='planCont' cols='60' rows='10' required></textarea>



        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Create Plan'>
    </form>";
```

Comment: Do a `print_r($students);` and see what is in it.

Comment: Nothing is printing.  So any ideas why my array is not populating with anything?

Comment: Can you show some more HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Your id for your `input` field should be `email`, not `$email`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Not sure how I missed this.  I fixed this error and did what @putvande suggested. Same issue still persists.

Comment: What's the return value of `mail`? Are you seeing any errors, or just not getting messages?

Comment: I'm just not getting the messages, unless like I mentioned I send to one email address.  I also can tell you that the message subject and message content submit to a database and that continues to work regardless of whether I receive the message or not.

Comment: You may have a problem with your host's email limitations. Also, be sure `print_r($students);` contains what you expect.

Comment: Thank you for helping me narrow down my issues. print_r($students); does not contain anything so I realized I have a problem with my checkbox array.  I just wish I could figure out what because I have used the same pattern to insert into my database from an array of checkboxes and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ed Cottrell and @putvande for your help. I finally figured it out. I was attempting to allow users to send HTML email.  In one of my original attempts I read I need this.

```
$_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );

        //collect form data
        extract($_POST);
```

But later on I changed direction so I did not need it anymore. I deleted that out and now everything  works. Again, thank you for your time.  I thought after a few hours of searching it was time to ask but I guess I should have waited 30 more minutes.